# How to use cucumber with TestNG without using maven

Tags: cucumber

> I am trying to run the "cucumber" without using maven dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is a build tools where we add dependency to get all desired jar files. you can have all jar without using maven only thing is, You have to manually download all cucumber, selenium and testNG jar file and add it to build library in your IDE. you have to add testNg plugin in you IDE too.

Comment: Can you explain this code 
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true) public void setUpClass() throws Exception { testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass()); } @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature",